# Akka, chaining Futures

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have three methods which return future, how do I properly chain them so that output from first one is passed to the second and second's return to third and finally send them all of the above data to final future. I am not sure this is the correct way to approach this problem.

```scala
Source
  .fromFuture(someFuture)
  .mapAsync(1)(modelData => queryModelData(modelQuery))
  .mapAsync(1)(modelId => findModelId(modelData))
  .mapAsync(1)(jobData => queryJobData(jobQuery))
  .mapAsync(1)(status => setModelStatus(modelData,modelId,jobData))
```

Comment: What is the reason you want to do in separate akka stream stages? It can be easily done with a for-comprehension outside of akka-stream Flow

Comment: each of the futures  are mongodb calls and each of the future method arguments depend on the preceding future output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain multiple Futures sequentially using `.flatMap` (or a for-comprehension which is syntactic sugar for the same).

e.g.

```scala
  Source
    .fromFuture(someFuture)
    .mapAsync(1){ data =>
       for { 
         modelData <- queryModelData(data)
         modelId <- findModelId(modelData)
         jobData <- queryJobData(modelId)
         status <- setModelStatus(modelData, modelId, jobData)
       } yield status
    }
```

Comment: How do I handle error conditions for each of the future methods?

Comment: The for-comprehension will "short-circuit" and fail with the first throwable if any of those calls return a failure.